# ACX2100 cannot boot to new version

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

My customer upgrades the version for ACX2100 from 12.3X54-D34.1 to 20.4R3-S2.6.
After adding software, they checked JUNOS Installation Software already 20.4R3-S2.6.

```
vipa@BGG0333SRT03> show version | match Kernel 
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]

vipa@BGG0333SRT03> show version | match "JUNOS Installation Software" 
JUNOS Installation Software [20.4R3-S2.6]
```

But they did not reboot the device immediately.
After about 1 month, they rebooted, but after booting, the device cannot boot with the new version 20.4R3-S2.6.

Does anyone face this issue?
Have any timer if we don't reboot the device after adding software, the device will remove the "JUNOS Installation Software"?

Thanks.

Comment: Imho, it's generally not a bright idea to update firmware and then not reboot for a longish time. Chances are that an involuntary reboot happens and the update breaks things at a very inconvenient time. You should first schedule the reboot during maintenance hours and then install the update just before that. Also, make sure that the planned update path is supported - going from 12 to 20 sounds like a *vast* jump.

Comment: Yes, it is the mistake of my customer. The key point is he took a snapshot after adding software, then reboot. He also did some configs after adding software and before rebooting. After booting successfully, the device cant upgrade to the new version, and the configs (that were added before) still remain.

Answer (score 2):

I found the root cause of this issue.

####Summary the issue

- Add software successfully but after rebooting device does not update the new version.

####Root cause

- After adding the software successfully, my customer did "request system snapshot slice alternate"
- Then reboot
  If we did the above steps --> After rebooting device does not update to the new version.

Pls find the reproduction log below:

```
####Summary the issue
- Add software successfully but after rebooting device does not update the new version.

####Root cause
- After adding the software successfully, my customer did "request system snapshot slice alternate"
- Then reboot
If we did the above steps --> After rebooting device does not update new version.

####Log reproduce the issue
--- JUNOS 12.3X54-D34.1 built 2018-06-14 10:22:59 UTC

SRT config template!!

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 
####Show version before adding software 20.4R3-S2.6
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show version 
Hostname: BGG0333SRT03
Model: acx2100
JUNOS Crypto Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS boot [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (ACX) [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Online Documentation [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Routing Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]

####Snapshot before adding software 20.4R3-S2.6
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> request system snapshot slice alternate 
Verifying compatibility of destination media partitions...
Running newfs (886MB) on internal media  / partition (da0s2a)...
Running newfs (93MB) on internal media  /config partition (da0s2e)...
Copying '/dev/da0s1a' to '/dev/da0s2a' .. (this may take a few minutes)
Copying '/dev/da0s1e' to '/dev/da0s2e' .. (this may take a few minutes)
The following filesystems were archived: / /config

####Add software version 20.4R3-S2.6
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> request system software add /var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6-signed.tgz 
NOTICE: Validating configuration against jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6-signed.tgz.
NOTICE: Use the 'no-validate' option to skip this if desired.
Checking compatibility with configuration
Initializing...
Using /packages1/jbase-ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_12_3_0
Using /var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6-signed.tgz
Verified jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Using jbundle-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Checking jbundle-ppc requirements on /
Using jbase-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jbase-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using /var/validate/chroot/tmp/jbundle-ppc/jboot-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Using jcrypto-dp-support-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jcrypto-dp-support-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jcrypto-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jcrypto-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jdocs-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jdocs-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jkernel-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jkernel-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jmacsec-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jmacsec-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jpfe-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified SHA1 checksum of jpfe-ACX-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified SHA1 checksum of jpfe-MX104-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified SHA1 checksum of jpfe-MX80-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jpfe-ACX-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jroute-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jroute-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jsd-powerpc-20.4R3-S2.6-jet-1.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jsd-powerpc-20.4R3-S2.6-jet-1 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jsdn-powerpc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Verified manifest signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Verified jsdn-powerpc-20.4R3-S2.6 signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Using jservices-crypto-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Using jservices-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz
Hardware Database regeneration succeeded
Validating against /config/juniper.conf.gz
mgd: commit complete
Validation succeeded
Installing package '/var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6-signed.tgz' ...
Verified jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6.tgz signed by PackageProductionSHA1RSA_2022
Adding jinstall-ppc...

WARNING:     This package will load JUNOS 20.4R3-S2.6 software.
WARNING:     It will save JUNOS configuration files, and SSH keys
WARNING:     (if configured), but erase all other files and information
WARNING:     stored on this machine.  It will attempt to preserve dumps
WARNING:     and log files, but this can not be guaranteed.  This is the
WARNING:     pre-installation stage and all the software is loaded when
WARNING:     you reboot the system.

Saving the config files ...
NOTICE: uncommitted changes have been saved in /var/db/config/juniper.conf.pre-install
Installing the bootstrap installer ...
copying files to /altroot

WARNING:     A REBOOT IS REQUIRED TO LOAD THIS SOFTWARE CORRECTLY. Use the
WARNING:     'request system reboot' command when software installation is
WARNING:     complete. To abort the installation, do not reboot your system,
WARNING:     instead use the 'request system software delete jinstall'
WARNING:     command as soon as this operation completes.

Saving package file in /var/sw/pkg/jinstall-ppc-20.4R3-S2.6-signed.tgz ...

Saving state for rollback ...
Setting active slice alternate

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 
####Show version after adding software 20.4R3-S2.6
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show version                            
Hostname: BGG0333SRT03
Model: acx2100
JUNOS Crypto Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS boot [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (ACX) [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Online Documentation [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Routing Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Installation Software [20.4R3-S2.6]

####Snapshot after adding software 20.4R3-S2.6
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> request system snapshot slice alternate 
Verifying compatibility of destination media partitions...
Running newfs (886MB) on internal media  / partition (da0s2a)...
Running newfs (93MB) on internal media  /config partition (da0s2e)...
Copying '/dev/da0s1a' to '/dev/da0s2a' .. (this may take a few minutes)
Copying '/dev/da0s1e' to '/dev/da0s2e' .. (this may take a few minutes)
The following filesystems were archived: / /config

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

####Show version before rebooting
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show version 
Hostname: BGG0333SRT03
Model: acx2100
JUNOS Crypto Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS boot [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (ACX) [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Online Documentation [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Routing Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Installation Software [20.4R3-S2.6]

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show system snapshot 
Information for snapshot on internal (da0s2)
Creation date: Nov 16 16:29:09 2022
JUNOS version on snapshot:
  jbase  : ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jcrypto: ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jdocs  : 12.3X54-D34.1
  jkernel: ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jpfe   : ACX-12.3X54-D34.1
  jroute : ppc-12.3X54-D34.1

####Reboot system
juniper@BGG0333SRT03> request system reboot 
Reboot the system ? [yes,no] (no) yes 

Shutdown NOW!
[pid 10184]

juniper@BGG0333SRT03>                                                                                
*** FINAL System shutdown message from remote@BGG0333SRT03 ***               

System going down IMMEDIATELY                                                  

                                                                               
####After booting successfully, the version is still 12.3X54-D34.1
--- JUNOS 12.3X54-D34.1 built 2018-06-14 10:22:59 UTC

SRT config template!!

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> 

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show version 
Hostname: BGG0333SRT03
Model: acx2100
JUNOS Crypto Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Base OS boot [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (ACX) [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Online Documentation [12.3X54-D34.1]
JUNOS Routing Software Suite [12.3X54-D34.1]

juniper@BGG0333SRT03> show system snapshot 
Information for snapshot on internal (da0s1)
Creation date: Nov 16 15:53:42 2022
JUNOS version on snapshot:
  jbase  : ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jcrypto: ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jdocs  : 12.3X54-D34.1
  jkernel: ppc-12.3X54-D34.1
  jpfe   : ACX-12.3X54-D34.1
  jroute : ppc-12.3X54-D34.1

juniper@BGG0333SRT03>
```

I would like to update you all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have no hands on experience with ACX, but on MX (running JunOS as well) you cannot just do such a major version bump from 12 to 20 without going via some intermediate releases. The JunOS installation software is unable to do the proper updates if you jump 8 versions. Reading the installation instructions of JunOS should give you hints on what the minimal version is you need to be able install JunOS 20, I expect it to be a 17 or 18 release.